# How do I create an atom dynamically in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I am trying to register a couple processess with atom names created dynamically, like so:

```
keep_alive(Name, Fun) ->
    register(Name, Pid = spawn(Fun)),
    on_exit(Pid, fun(_Why) -> keep_alive(Name, Fun) end).

monitor_some_processes(N) ->
    %% create N processes that restart automatically when killed
    for(1, N, fun(I) ->
                             Mesg = io_lib:format("I'm process ~p~n", [I]),
                             Name = list_to_atom(io_lib:format("zombie~p", [I])),
                             keep_alive(Name, fun() -> zombie(Mesg) end)
                     end).

for(N, N, Fun) -> [Fun(N)];
for(I, N, Fun) -> [Fun(I)|for(I+1, N, Fun)].

zombie(Mesg) ->
    io:format(Mesg),
    timer:sleep(3000),
    zombie(Mesg).
```

That `list_to_atom/1` call though is resulting in an error:

```
43> list_to_atom(io_lib:format("zombie~p", [1])).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  list_to_atom/1
        called as list_to_atom([122,111,109,98,105,101,"1"])
```

What am I doing wrong?
Also, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You should beware that atoms are not garbage-collected and live until the Erlang VM is terminated. This means that if you create lots of atoms, you will use lots of memory.

Comment: Never, ever do this. Ever. The Post Police decided to delete my answer which was too tongue-in-cheek for their tastes but represents a basic Erlang consensus on this subject and the Standard Answer. *Don't* dynamically generate atoms. Ever. You never need to do this and every time you do something ugly is spawned in the universe. Too bad this place has *totally* lost its sense of humor. :-/

Comment: @zxq9 I hear ya, "generating atoms dynamically may cause lots of problems and is usually not what you want". What would be a better way of doing this? I appreciate you taking the time to answer, but you should know that hearing a dogmatic answer without an alternative solution is also hard, specially when I've done what you say I shouldn't do and no kitten was killed. :) Sorry if your answer did offered a solution, I don't think I got to see it.

Comment: Because the accepted answer only demonstrates how to do something that should not be done at all, my original answer was designed to discourage its use in a memorable way. Sometime in the last few years this has become taboo on StackExchange, so it was killed mercilessly by some folks with apparently little Erlang background, as per SO standard moderation practice. My new answer indicates gproc, which works well but you probably don't actually need in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`io_lib:format` returns a potentially "deep list" (i.e. it may contain other lists), while `list_to_atom` requires a "flat list".  You can wrap the `io_lib:format` call in a call to `lists:flatten`:

```
list_to_atom(lists:flatten(io_lib:format("zombie~p", [1]))).
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I was able to get it working with `list_to_atom(binary_to_list(iolist_to_binary(..)))` but using flatten is much better.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**

You should not dynamically generate atoms. From what your code snippet indicates you are probably trying to find some way to flexibly name processes, but atoms are not it. Use a K/V store of some type instead of `register/2`.

**Discussion**

Atoms are restrictive for a reason. They should represent something about the eternal *structure* of your program, not the current *state* of it. Atoms are so restrictive that I imagine what you *really* want to be able to do is register a process using any arbitrary Erlang value, not just atoms, and reference them more freely.

If that is the case, pick from one of the following four approaches:

1. Keep Key/Value pairs somewhere to act as your own registry. This could be a separate process or a list/tree/dict/map handler to store key/value pairs of `#{Name => Pid}`.
2. Use the [global](http://erlang.org/doc/man/global.html) module (which, like gproc below, has features that work across a cluster).
3. Use a registry solution like Ulf Wiger's nice little project [gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc). It is awesome for the times when you actually need it (which are, honestly, not as often as I see it used). Here is a decent blog post about its use and why it works the way it does: http://blog.rusty.io/2009/09/16/g-proc-erlang-global-process-registry/. An added advantage of gproc is that nearly every Erlanger you'll meet is at least passingly familiar with it.
4. A variant on the first option, structure your program as a tree of service managers and workers (as in the ["Service -> Worker Pattern"](https://zxq9.com/archives/1311)). A side effect of this pattern is that *very often* the service manager winds up needing to monitor its process for one reason or another if you're doing anything non-trivial, and that makes it an ideal candidate for a place to keep a Key/Value registry of Pids. It is quite common for this sort of pattern to wind up emerging naturally as a program matures, *especially* if that program has high robustness requirements. Structuring it as a set of semi-independent services with an abstract management interface at the top of each from the outset is often a handy evolutionary shortcut.